# Иностранные слова в предложении

Tags: стилистика

Допустимо ли на сайте использование иностранных слов без перевода?
Например: *Расчёты на платформе  производятся в одной валюте, работающей на Blockchain*. И лучше писать: соцсети, соц. сети или социальные сети; онлайн-платформа или онлайновая?

Comment: По поводу "онлайновой платформы":http://maximilyahov.ru/blog/all/online-internet/Онлайн — это существительное, а не наречие. Обозначает условное виртуальное пространство, а не способ что-то делать. Слово «онлайн» склоняется и используется с предлогом: в онлайне, во имя онлайна.

Answer (score 1):

Если текст ориентирован на подготовленного читателя,  использование иностранных слов без перевода вполне корректно.

Что касается сокращений. В словаре соращений и аббревиатур (Академик. 2015.) представлен такой вариант: соцсеть. Ср. другие слова из этой группы: соцпакет, соцработник соцопрос и.т. д. В тексте можно использовать два варианта: социальная сеть и соцсеть.

Правильно: **онлайн-платформа.**

онлайн, -а и **неизм**.

онлайн-… – первая часть сложных слов, пишется через дефис

**Орфографический академический словарь Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН**

Comment: По поводу "онлайновой платформы":maximilyahov.ru/blog/all/online-internet/Онлайн — это существительное, а не наречие. Обозначает условное виртуальное пространство, а не способ что-то делать. Слово «онлайн» склоняется и используется с предлогом: в онлайне, во имя онлайна. –

Comment: Слово онлайн не только существительное, но и наречие. Напр.: оработать онлайн.

Answer (score 1):

Использование иностранных слов без перевода мне кажется некорректным. Я отношу себя к "неподготовленным" читателям.

Бесконечно сталкиваюсь с проблемой чтения и перевода английских слов, так как второй язык у меня немецкий. Если текст создаётся на русском языке, все слова в нём должны быть оформлены по-русски. Можно использовать скобки с пояснениями и переводом или ссылки, если обойтись без иностранного слова, написанного на иностранном языке, невозможно.

Онлайн-платформа, конечно.